# big mysql file doesn't deploy every database in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wamp

I am trying to import an sql file to phpmyadmin in wamp. I used the next line in command prompt:

```
 mysql -h yourhostname -u username < yoursqlfile.sql
```

I works for the first 5 database in the sql file, but then it stops and it still has 10 databases to go. I thought I maybe had the do with max_input_time, so i adjusted that in php.ini file but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I accesed the php.ini by clicking on wamp symbole. so normally I have the right file.

Comment: enable verbose mode  `mysql -h yourhostname -u username -v < yoursqlfile.sql ` to see what is happening.
Also check mysql log for error

Comment: The mysql.exe processor has nothing to do with PHP so any changes to `php.ini` would be irrelevant! Have you looked in the `mysql error log` to look for error messages? Can you breakup the sql file into smaller pieces?